# How can I apply lambda function to 2 values in a row (lambda> missing 1 required argument)?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, multiple-columns, apply

I have a dataset of 2 columns: age_group, target(0,1). 
I want to create 3rd column "count"(value counts of age_group). It has to look up if target is good and bad and put its corresponding count.

5 bins for ages:

```
df['age_group'] = pd.cut(df['age'], [17,22,26,32,45,50,60])
```

40 rows:

```
age_group       target
0   (45, 50]    bad
1   (45, 50]    bad
2   (32, 45]    good
3   (32, 45]    good
4   (50, 60]    bad
5   (32, 45]    bad
6   (26, 32]    good
7   (50, 60]    good
8   (32, 45]    bad
9   (17, 22]    good
10  (32, 45]    good
```

I could groupby by target:

```
df.groupby('target').age_group.value_counts().to_frame()

                          age_group
target       age_group  
bad          (32, 45]      7
             (26, 32]      3
             (45, 50]      3
             (50, 60]      3
             (17, 22]      2
good         (32, 45]      8
             (17, 22]      4
             (50, 60]      4
             (45, 50]      3
             (26, 32]      2
             (22, 26]      1
```

but in this dataframe only age_group is the main accessible column. I can't access 'target' column and specific values for good, bad target.

I want to look up each age_group  AND its target and put the corresponding value in "count" column.

so I'm doing this ugly workaround function.

```
def get_value_count_for_age_group_category(age_group, target):
    bad_vals = df[df['bad']==1]['age_group'].value_counts().sort_index()
    good_vals = df[df['good']==1]['age_group'].value_counts().sort_index()
    values = age_freq.values.tolist()
    keys = age_freq.keys()
    if target == 'bad':
        for k in keys:        
            if age_group == pd.Interval(32,45):            
                return bad_vals[0]    
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(50, 60):
                return bad_vals[1]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(45, 50):
                return bad_vals[2]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(26, 32):
                return bad_vals[3]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(22, 26):
                return bad_vals[4]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(17,22):
                return bad_vals[5]
    else:
        for k in keys:        
            if age_group == pd.Interval(32,45):            
                return good_vals[0]    
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(50, 60):
                return good_vals[1]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(45, 50):
                return good_vals[2]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(26, 32):
                return good_vals[3]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(22, 26):
                return good_vals[4]
            elif age_group == pd.Interval(17,22):
                return good_vals[5]
```

this is not working, passing 2 values - age_group and its target to a lambda function:

```
n['count'] = n[['age_group', 'target']].apply(lambda num:get_value_count_for_age_group_category(num, target) )
```

> lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument:

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: @moys, my output is df with 3 columns, similar to groupby function i wrote. I want 3rd column added to main dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
df.groupby('target').age_group.value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
```

**Input**

```
age_group   target
0   (45, 50)    bad
1   (45, 50)    bad
2   (32, 45)    good
3   (32, 45)    good
4   (50, 60)    bad
5   (32, 45)    bad
6   (26, 32)    good
7   (50, 60)    good
8   (32, 45)    bad
9   (17, 22)    good
10  (32, 45)    good
```

**Output**

```
  target    age_group   count
0   bad     (32, 45)    2
1   bad     (45, 50)    2
2   bad     (50, 60)    1
3   good    (32, 45)    3
4   good    (17, 22)    1
5   good    (26, 32)    1
6   good    (50, 60)    1
```

If 'zero' vales are alse needed, plesae use below

```
df1=df.groupby('target').age_group.value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
df1.set_index(['target','age_group']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```

**output**

```
  target    age_group   count
0   bad     (17, 22)    0
1   bad     (26, 32)    0
2   bad     (32, 45)    2
3   bad     (45, 50)    2
4   bad     (50, 60)    1
5   good    (17, 22)    1
6   good    (26, 32)    1
7   good    (32, 45)    3
8   good    (45, 50)    0
9   good    (50, 60)    1
```

Comment: i always suspect there is one liner in pandas. but i dont know it.. so i try to write some horrible pile of code

Comment: also that one liner is  not giving age_group if its count is 0! to build a bar chart by target i need all values for all age groups..